# Reusing the input stream variable

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

Consider the following code snippet `getInputStreamForRead()` method creates and returns a new input stream for read.

```
InputStream is = getInputStreamForRead();    //This method creates and returns an input stream for file read
is = getDecompressedStream(is);
```

Since the orginal file content is compressed and stored it has to be decompressed while reading. Hence `getDecompressedStream()` method below would provide option to decompress the stream content

```
public InputStream getDecompressedStream(InputStream is) throws Exception {
 return new GZIPInputStream(is);
}
```

**Have the following doubts**

1. Which one is correct for the above snippet

   ```
   is = getDecompressedStream(is)
   ```

   or

   ```
   InputStream newStream = getDecompressedStream(is)
   ```
2. Will reusing the `InputStream` variable again cause any trouble?

I'm completely new with streams. Kindly help me to know about this.

Comment: I believe inputstream is just another object and it will be reassigned with new value. 1 should be ok.

Comment: You could test this on your own by trying it. But they'll both do the same thing. Both are valid options

Comment: Can I assume/understand like stream instance similar to a class instance? Or does the stream instance, has any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as:

- you're not manipulating the original `InputStream` between the original assignment and the new invocation
- you're always closing your streams in a `finally` statement

... you should be fine re-assigning to the original variable - it's just a new value passed to an existing reference.

In fact, that may be the recommended way, since you get to only close one `Closeable` programmatically, as `GZIPInputStream#close`...

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.

(see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html#close%28%29) - I read this as, "closes the underlying stream").

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to close the input stream correctly, the best way is to create the input stream using chaining, and using a try-with-resources to handle the close for you.

```
try (InputStream is = getDecompressedStream(getInputStreamForRead())) {
    // code using stream here
}
```

Comment: Yeah @Andreas It seems to be a good option for closing the input stream. But I would like to know whether the input stream can be reused. ie; Whether reassigning the `InputStream` instance  with some other value would cause any trouble.

Comment: For an example the value of a final variable cannot be changed. Likewise for an `InputStream` instance variable reusing/reassigning it cause any trouble?

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian You comments are confusing, so let me answer like this: 1) A variable can be reused, you just lose the previous value when you reassign. If you don't need that value anymore, there is no problem. 2) An `InputStream` cannot be reused. You can only read the stream once.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas you have explained really well. Got a clear picture.